# How to get Taxonomy Term Field Value in twig

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term with the name 'Colors' and it has 1 image field called field_color_image. In my project I have a node type with a field type of Taxonomy term that refer to Colors. My aim is that I want to show the image in the Colors taxonomy to a node. I already used kint and it didn't really help. How do I achieve this? Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the url of your term reference image inside the node twig try:

```
node.field_color_term.0.entity.field_color_image.entity.uri.0.value
```

Change `field_color_term` by your field name.

There is another way by configuring the display of your content type and your term like the following:

1. Content type display should be like 
   [image]
2. Taxonomy term display should be like 
   [image]

After this configuration you can render your field type of Taxonomy term, it will show the image:

```
{{ content.field_YOURFIELDNAME }}
```

Comment: node.field_color_term.0.entity.field_color_image.entity.uri.0.value really saved the day! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, i'm glad that helped !